# Linear Approximation

Tags: calculus

I have an exercise, giving this question.

> Find the linear approximation $Y$ to $f(x)$ near $x=a$.
>   $$
> f(x) = x + x^4,\quad a=0
> $$

I can see in my result list that it says $Y=x$, however, after multiple tries I can only convince myself that it gives $Y=0$.

Can anyone explain why it gives $1$ and not $0$?

Comment: Do you know how to derive a polynomial function?

Comment: It's unfortunate that this simultaneously has the "calculus" and "algebra-precalculus" tags - it makes it difficult to know whether or not calculus is acceptable! I assume it probably is given the nature of the question, but still :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any differentiable function $f$, the best linear approximation to $f(x)$ at the point $x=a$ is the line defined by
$$y=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a).$$
(Intuitively, this makes sense: $f'(a)$ is like "*the slope of $f$ at $a$*", and the line with slope $f'(a)$ that goes through the point $(a,f(a))$ is precisely the one specified above).

Can you find the derivative of $f(x)=x+x^4$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: yes, I can find the derivative of a. I think the problem is that I set x=0 also in the (x-a) paranthesis - I am not supposed to do this I assume? The derivative is; 1+4x^3...

Comment: Yes, the line is just like any other being specified in a form $y=mx+b$ or $y=m(x-s)+t$ or whatever; $x$ is the input variable, $y$ is the output variable. I understand why it might be confusing because $f'(a)$ and $f(a)$ are just numbers (even though they may not seem to be), and because $a=0$, but we never set $x$ equal to anything.

Comment: It's $a$ that gets set $=0$, not $x$ :)

Comment: @user1090614: Okay, so you've correctly found that
$$f'(x)=1+4x^3.$$
What is $f'(a)$, when $a=0$?

Comment: I got it now, if I am not supposed to set x, its no problem at all. I think, as Sharkos writes in a comment to the previous answer, that it is perhaps given the nature of the question. It says in my questions "x=a", and im not very confident in english, so I easily misunderstand things. I get the point that Y=x, since 0+1(x-0) = 1.